# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "capitán Araña"?

Tags: expresiones, modismos, historia, animales

¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "capitán Araña", que en forma más completa es "Capitán Araña, que embarca a la gente y se queda en tierra"?

El uso más antiguo que he visto (pero que no explica el origen) es de 1877: Ricardo Palma, "Tradiciones peruanas":

> Lo curioso es que el alcalde de Paucarcolla era como el **capitán Araña**, que decía: -¡Embarca, embarca!- y él se quedaba en tierra de España.

Comment: En Chile decimos "_el capitán Araya, que embarca a la gente y se queda en la playa_". Araya es un apellido común.

Comment: [Acá](https://books.google.cl/books?id=DnhaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP13&dq=capitan+ara%C3%B1a&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwilk-_iq_rzAhVXFrkGHVQfBcUQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=capitan%20ara%C3%B1a&f=false) hay un ejemplo de 1750.

Answer (score 2):

En [este blog](https://mrjaen.com/2022/08/12/el-capitan-arana/) se indica:

> El origen de esta frase hay que buscarlo en la figura del capitán Arana o Aranha, un personaje del siglo XVIII que recorría el litoral de la península Ibérica con la intención de reclutar gente con destino a las colonias de América para luchar contra los insurrectos, sin que él jamas emprendiera viaje alguno hacia el Nuevo Continente.